# Mixing PHP and Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For one of my project, I am developing a website with PHP. I'd like to know if it would be possible to mix it with Rails?

Ruby on Rails would query data on GitHub and I would like to process it with PHP, is that possible? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible. You just have to write a small webservice with RoR that gets the data from github and give it to your php frontend in a defined format (rest service with json for example).

But i don't think it make sense if one person write one website with 2 languages...

Comment: No, it would be another person doing the Rails part

Comment: @Moustachauve well then it might be okay. i've often seen mixes in the language / technology stack. for example the frontends with php, ruby or javascript and the middleware sytems with java.

Comment: My advice is to stick to 1 language. You will need double functions increasing the development time almost 2 fold. Not to mention the confusion.
As for the actual answer you need like a bus between the 2 languages. JSONs are a good way to go, but they need a lot of coding to extract the data in desired format